# C# Windows form delete key not responding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

in my C# windows form application I want the user to be able to remove a node by pressing the delete key on their keyboard and have implemented the seemingly correct code but when the delete key is pressed nothing happens.

```
        private void treeView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys .Delete)
        {

            if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
            {
                treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
            }
        }
```

This is the code I am attempting to use to implement the desired function.

Comment: have you put a breakpointint in the handler to see if that code is executed?

Comment: I just tried that and it seems that the code in question is never even executed

Comment: The view may just be out of focus, in which case it will not receive key events. So, you either focus programmaticaly: treeView.Focus(...), or use CoreWindow instead: Window.Current.CoreWindows.KeyDown+=...

Comment: Why don't you ask your best fried, the debugger???

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard keycode check looks fine to me, which says to me that treeView1.SelectedNode is probably returning null.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem today and have tried many ways to address it. MSDN gives the answer actually. Here are the two codes that I put in `public Form1()`

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
```

I've just study C# this week, so I am trying to figure out the meaning of the codes. Just hope this approach will work for the people who needs.

If anyone can explain the code above, I will be very grateful.